# How to parse a list in Python that might have whitespace and returning JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5) errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list in Python3

```
mylist=['"{  "score": "Really Good",  "text": "This is a text accompanying the score, level, and more.",  "level": "high level"}"',
 '"{  "score": "Not So Good",  "text": "This is a text accompanying the score, level, and more.",  "level": "high level"}"']
```

I would like to access each of the elements in `mylist`, such as `score`,`key`,`text`. When I try to do

```
scores = [json.loads(json_str)["score"] for json_str in mylist]
```

I get the error `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)`. My suspicion is that it is because of whitespace, and more (single quotes on outside). How can I parse this correctly?

Comment: What is the point of the first set of double quotes?

Comment: There is no point to it, it is an artifact I need to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra set of double quotes in each string. You can either remove them manually or just slice them out like this:

```
scores = [json.loads(json_str[1:-1])["score"] for json_str in mylist]
```